# Gradle: project depends on libraries but is not a library itself

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have android solution that contains 3 projects:

- **app**. Presentation layer, that contains logic for UI. Android application project;
- **domain**. Business logic. Java library project;
- **data**. Data storage. Android library project;

App depends on domain. Domain depends on data.

Here is build.gradle of the **app** project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':domain')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.github.asne.facebook:facebook:3.17.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

build.gradle of the **domain** project:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


dependencies {
    compile project(':data')
}
```

build.gradle of the **data** project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1'
}
```

The probles is that I get an error and the message of this error that **domain** layer `depends on libraries but is not a library itself`. What's wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to remove the dependency of Domain on Data. Instead, inject the data provider into domain. There is a nice [article](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) that gives a clue on how different application parts should be related to make unit testing painless.

The alternative would be to follow @frederick nyawaya's answer and use [this tutorial](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/) to set up unit testing with Robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle for **domain**, add: `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Comment: So is it impossible to use pure java for **domain**? In this way we can use junit 4 and we can test it easily.

Comment: A plain Java project can't depend on an Android project. Android projects are more complicated and the Java plugin doesn't know what to do with them.